# String sort function from c to assembly seg faulting

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

So I need to convert given C code [a sort function] into assembly code and I have done that so far but when I'm running test cases for it, they're all seg faulting.
Here are what the test cases should return once sort is run:

- sorted list = {abl, bal, bla, blo, bol, lab, lob, obl}
- sorted list = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800}
- sorted list = {apple, banana, blueberry, kiwi, mango, orange, peach, strawberry}

I'm not too sure what's going on, I've explained each line of assembly I wrote and I'm struggling to find the point of error in my code. Any suggestions/recs on where to fix the issue would be great as im pretty new to assembly! thank you all.

Here is the C code I need to replicate in assembly:

```
void sort(char **list, int n) {
    int sorted=0, i=1, j;
    char *temp;
    while (i < n && !sorted) {
        j=0;
        sorted = 1;
        while (j<n-i) {
            if (cmp(list[j], list[j+1]) > 0) {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j+1];
                list[j+1] = temp;
                sorted = 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int cmp(char *str1, char *str2) {
    while (*str1 && (*str1 == *str2)) {
       str1++;
       str2++;
    }
    return *str1 - *str2;
}
```

And here is the assembly code I wrote for the given C code:

```
.global sort
sort:
    # we push callee saved regs for the first 2 lines: 
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rbp 
    #set the 2 registers to 0 
    movq $0, %rbx
    movq $0, %rbp
    #save n in ebx: 
    movl %esi, %ebx
    #saving pointer list 
    movq %rdi, %rbp
    #sorted here 
    movq $0, %rdx 
    #i 
    movq $1, %rcx
    #j 
    movq $0, %r8 
    #*temp being initialized: 
    movq $0, %r9 
    retq

#first while loop 
.L1: 
    #compare i and n 
    cmpl %ebx, %ecx
    #if greater than, jump to L2 
    jge .L2 
    #comparing sorted/sorted
    testl %edx, %edx 
    #if not equal, go to the while loop: 
    je .L3 

.L2: 
    #need to pop these values before we can return: 
    popq %rbp
    popq %rbx 
    ret

#second while loop: 
.L3: 
    #setting j = 0 
    movl $0, %r8d
    #setting sorted to 1:
    movl $1, %edx 

.inner: 
    #bringing n: 
    movl %ebx, %esi 
    #n-i 
    subl %ecx, %esi 
    #compare n-i and j: 
    cmpl %r8d, %esi 
    #if greater than, jump to L4: 
    je .L4 

L8: 
    #getting list[j]:
    movq (%rbp,%r8,8), %rdi 
    #list[j+1]
    movq 8(%rbp,%r8,8), %rsi 
    call cmp 
    #test result:
    testb %al, %al 
    #jump to L7 if less than or = to 0: 
    jle .L7 
    #list[j] is now in rax 
    movq (%rbp, %r8, 8), %rax 
    #temp = list[j +1] 
    movq 8(%rbp, %r8, 8), %r10
    #list[j+1] = list[j]
    movq %rax, 8(%rbp, %r8, 8)
    #list[j] = list[j+1]
    movq %r10, (%rbp, %r8, 8)
    #set edx to zero: 
    movl $0, %edx 

.L7: 
    #incrementing j in this label
    incl %r8d 
    #jmp back to inner while loop 
    jmp .inner 

.L4: 
    #incrementing i:
    incl %ecx 
    #go to L1- outer while loop 
    jmp .L1 

cmp: 
    #%al = *str1
    movb (%rdi), %al
    #r11b = *str2 
    movb (%rsi), %r11b
    .L5: 
        #comparing str1 pointers to each other 
        testb %al, %al
        #if != 0, go to L6: 
        je .L6 
        #al -r11d
        cmpb %r11b, %al
        #if != 0 go to L6 
        jne .L6 
        #rdi++
        incq %rdi
        #rsi++
        incq %rsi 
        jmp cmp 
    .L6: 
        #al - r11b
        subb %r11b, %al 
        ret
```

Comment: Which instruction faults?  Use a debugger to find out, e.g. `gdb`.  Note that your `cmp` (`strcmp`) is only safe for 7-bit ASCII characters, so the max difference is +-127.  Otherwise an 8-bit subtraction isn't wide enough for the sign bit to capture the compare result.  Either use FLAGS as the return value, or zero-extend the bytes that differ and subtract those, like implementations of C `memcmp` / `strcmp` do.  This is the same reason that `jl` is `SF != OF`, rather than just `SF`

Comment: its at line "movq $0, %rdx" that it says "Cannot access memory at address 0x0

0x00007fffffffd940 in ?? ()"

Comment: That instruction doesn't access memory; it can't fault except on code-fetch, but it's not the first instruction in a block so even putting your code in a non-executable section wouldn't explain it.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `movq 0, %rdx` instead?  That is a load from absolute address `0` and would segfault the way GDB reported.  Maybe you forgot to rebuild after editing the asm?

Comment: This code appears a bit odd.  The `sort` routine never calls or executes the `first while loop` or the `second while loop`.  It gets called, sets a few registers, then returns.  That doesn't seem right.  I do notice that you push 2 registers when you call `sort`, but never pop them back off.  That's likely to cause a crash when you ret.

Comment: actually i just figured it out, it was the retq statement that I had to remove in the "sort". thank you!

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way will be comparing it to the C compiler generated code:

```
cmp:
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
.L3:
        movsbl  (%rdi,%rcx), %eax
        movsbl  (%rsi,%rcx), %edx
        testb   %al, %al
        je      .L2
        incq    %rcx
        cmpb    %dl, %al
        je      .L3
.L2:
        subl    %edx, %eax
        ret
sort:
        movslq  %esi, %rax
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rdi, %r9
        movl    $1, %ebp
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rax, %r10
        leaq    -8(%rdi,%rax,8), %rbx
        xorl    %r11d, %r11d
.L10:
        cmpl    %r10d, %ebp
        jge     .L9
        testl   %r11d, %r11d
        jne     .L9
        movq    %r9, %r8
        movl    $1, %r11d
.L12:
        movq    8(%r8), %rsi
        movq    (%r8), %rdi
        call    cmp
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jle     .L11
        movq    %rsi, (%r8)
        xorl    %r11d, %r11d
        movq    %rdi, 8(%r8)
.L11:
        addq    $8, %r8
        cmpq    %r8, %rbx
        jne     .L12
        incl    %ebp
        subq    $8, %rbx
        jmp     .L10
.L9:
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Comment: A dump of some random assembly code does not suffice as an answer.

Comment: As the person writing the answer, you should be doing the comparing and pointing out which differences are significant.  If you don't want to do that, this should have just been a comment with the Godbolt link.